# Is it safe to do dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/<destination partition>

Tags: partitioning, dd

I want to wipe one of my partitions say `sda2` (I don't care about data security in this case). Does 
`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2`
damage `sda1` and `sda3` or even partition table?

Comment: It is quite safe if you are sure that `sda2` is the correct one ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda2` (needs to run as root or with `sudo`) does only overwrite the complete `/dev/sda2` partition with zero-bytes, nothing else.

It will neither affect other partitions nor the partition table.

---

Only if you have a SSD, you should not do this, because the memory cells of an SSD wear out by overwriting them and because a software block address does not correspond to a fixed hardware memory cell. That means you can not overwrite a specific memory cell anyway.